# Trouble with xacro tags without the namespace in ROS Jade

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, Everyone

I am using ROS Jade in Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to run the following command:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py `rospack find pr2_description`/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro > pr2.urdf
```

However I receive the following error message

```
   deprecated: xacro tags should be prepended with 'xacro' xml namespace.
Use the following script to fix incorrect usage:
        find . -iname "*.xacro" | xargs sed -i 's#<\([/]\?\)\(if\|unless\|include\|arg\|property\|macro\|insert_block\)#<\1xacro:\2#g'
when processing file: /opt/ros/jade/share/pr2_description/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro
```

As the error message itself suggests, I ran the above script in a terminal. When I do it the following message appears:

```
sed: no input files
```

After trying to build the pr2.urdf file again I kept receiving the same error message as before.

I also tried to run the command to build the pr2.urdf file as follows:

```
rosrun xacro xacro --inorder `rospack find pr2_description`/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro > pr2.urdf
```

Then I receive a error message that says (The same error message is repeated for different .xacro files, so I am ommiting part of the error message for brevity)

```
inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
 old: http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface
 new: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro (/opt/ros/jade/share/pr2_description/urdf/shoulder_v0/shoulder.urdf.xacro)
inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
 old: http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface
 new: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro (/opt/ros/jade/share/pr2_description/urdf/upper_arm_v0/upper_arm.urdf.xacro)
```

I am a new ROS and Ubuntu user, and though I have searched the web for a solution I haven't been able to fix the error on my own.

Would you be able to help me fixing this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250897/trouble-with-xacro-tags-without-the-namespace-in-ros-jade/) by [Ari.Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/28913/ari.schneider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case, I had also the following warning:

```
inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
old: http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro
new: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro (/home/andreu/dev/ros_ws/src/ensenso_nx/urdf/ensenso_n35.urdf.xacro)
```

the warning disappeared by setting the url in the top of the xacro file (robot tag) to: "http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"  instead of just "http://ros.org/wiki/xacro"

Don't ask me why...

---

Originally posted by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) with karma: 169 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-04-13**:
Yeah, that's a silly warning. The formats must all match. Either all http://www.ros... or all http://ros... So you must have included another xacro file with a different format.